# C++14 increment a value inside of lambda function with capture-specifier

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

My task is to write a lambda function which increment a value, but I have to use value = 0 capture-specifier. I'm thinking about the following function:

```
auto lambda = [value = 0]{return ++value}
```

When this function is called it has to give an incremented value every time. But I know this implementation is wrong, because it's passed by value. How can I do this in C++14?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to make the lambda mutable:

```
auto lambda = [value = 0]() mutable {return ++value;};
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a capture:

```
[]{ static int i=0; return ++i; }
```

Is all you need.

Comment: What's the advantage of this over a `[value = 0]` capture?

Comment: This one can be converted to a function pointer because it is capture-less.

Comment: The disadvantage is that multiple instances of the lambda share the same counter instead of counting independently.

Comment: @Raymond you say disadvantage, I say feature. You're absolutely correct, but neither is better than the other in principle. Both have their use cases.

Comment: It depends on what the OP is trying to do. Just calling out that the two versions are not equivalent. One gives each lambda a separate counter. The other uses a single counter shared by all lambdas.